# css set size of content having image for different html elements

Tags: html, css

I am working on an E-commerce design where I was using following css class to display Rs. currency before product price.

```
 .rupes:before {
        content: 'Rs.';
    }
```

Now my requirement changed and I have to replace Rs. with Rs symbol so I used the following css:

```
.rupes:before {
    content: url(img/rupeess.png);
}
```

Now my question is, I have to change the size of Rs symbol , as the width of price.
Since class rupes is used on overall website 
on some page the Rs symbol is very small and on some page its very large.
So, is there any way to use same class, but inherit the size i.e, width of price for Rs Symbol.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other option is instead of an image you can use the Rupee character that should be in most default fonts since Windows XP. This will lower the resources for your site, and will always scale nicely...

```
.rupes::before{
    font-family: Arial;
    content:"\20b9";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nqadgqgy/1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the width or height in `em` to be relative to the font-size of the displayed price.

```
.rupes {
    content: '';
    background: url(img/rupeess.png) no-repeat center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}
```

Setting the width and height to the same value assumes a square icon. You may also use other icon ratios, e.g 4:3 (`width: 1.25em; height: 1em;`).

**Usage example:**

```
.price {
    font-size: 16px;
}


.big-price {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Display the pseudo element with a size of 16×16 pixel:

```
<p class="rupes price">123</p>
```

Display the pseudo element with a size of 24×24 pixel:

```
<p class="rupes big-price">456</p>
```

That way, the image is always as big or small as the font-size is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `position:absolute` on .rupes:before and `position:relative` on .rupes and then you can set the height and width of absolute div in percent..